# Data Analysis Work-- Is there Any Freelance Opportunity?

Tags: careers

Just wonder, is there any data analysis/ statistic/ data mining work that are available on freelance basis?

This could be subjective and argumentative, which is why I put it as CW.

Comment: Have you voted for close? It is strange that since without Shane we couldn't close any question...

Comment: I do think this could be rephrased in such a way that it would be on-topic (eg about the kind of work that statistical consultants do), but this is more like a job request.

Comment: @mbq Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Yes I voted to close. All 500+ rep users can (which means 8 users).

Comment: @Shane So you're here... I've got an impression that you should be holidating.
@Shane, @Peter Still, the problem exists, because not all of this eight is active in closing.

Comment: @mbq: I am vacationing, but occasionally my iPhone gets service.  And let's face it: I'm addicted to this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes". Such work does exist.
For example, there is sometimes consulting work in and around universities.
Also, some companies wish to outsource data analysis and statistical activities.

In general, I found that word of mouth was a powerful tool. Once you build up a good reputation in a given community, additional requests for work will follow.

see: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=statistics+jobs